# Could not find androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.10

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin, android-studio, build.gradle

I recently upgraded my React Native project to Expo 49, and since this I am unable to build my app for Android.

When attempting to generate a new signed APK or AAB, I get the following error:

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':dimaportenko_react-native-shadow-view:compileReleaseAidl'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':dimaportenko_react-native-shadow-view:releaseCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.10.
     Required by:
         project :dimaportenko_react-native-shadow-view
```

I have found suggestions online saying to add things such as:

`implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.10")` to my `build.gradle` dependencies

```
kotlinOptions {
     jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

to my `build.gradle`

However I have had no luck with any of these suggestions. My app is targeting Android version 33, and already sets the `kotlinVersion` to `1.8.10`.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

all releases are listed [HERE](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/core), there is no 1.8.10 version... consider using 1.8.0 or even better: update to newest one

KTX versioning isn't same as language versioning, e.g. currently KTX newest stable version is 1.12 and Kotlin stable version is 1.9.10

Comment: I changed my ``kotlinVersion`` to ``1.9.10``, this did resolve the issue above, however I am now getting an error:

``Execution failed for task ':app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.``

Comment: When I expand the error, I just have multiple errors relating to ``BuildConfig`` and ``ReactNativeFlipper`` like ``error: cannot find symbol
        return BuildConfig.DEBUG``